# Remove object function calls and communicate over REST web services c#

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, delegates, eventhandler

We have a system which has multiple components(projects) that communicate with one another. We reference other project dll's in our own component and use the functionalities provided by the other dll's. We do so by creating an instance of the class and invoking functions or APIs or events in the other dll.

Now we have a requirement that we want to decouple our component from the rest of the components in the system and take it outside the system.

We cannot reference the other project dll's because we are now outside the system.

But still we want to use the functionality provided by the other project dll.

Naturally, we wanted to use REST Web services to communicate with other components.

The difficulty here is, we have some event handlers listening to some events on other components and then do some activity on our components and we also have delegates

How do we acheive those functionatily over Web services?

Is Web services the correct way to go forward?

I am kinda stuck on this for a week or so and really out of ideas.

Any pointers or leads will be really helpful.

Comment: Sounds like that decision has more impact on the need for redesign than you expected. Do you have a clear view of what the "new" system layout shall be capable of?

Comment: Yes. We have to redesign our entire component, take care of all the wirings and all those things. We develop our component independently and then install it on the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to subscribe for events or be notified for something you can achieve this using Messaging Systems such RabbitMQ , Kafka or MSMQ. You should publish the message or notification to some exchange(talking in RabbitMQ terms https://www.rabbitmq.com/) and subscribe from the other side.

I think it is the best way to get notified for something that occurs in other part of the system. Then your subscriber that is listening for that messages / notifications can act depending the input.

Regarding the delegates maybe you can explain a little more what do you want to achieve.

Hope this helps.

EDIT** ; This is an example of the publish/subscribe pattern that I think fits perfectly on your model : https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html .

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this. Whenever the user or customers requests some resource from our Component and it is not available , we call other components and fetch the info and send it back to the customers. We delegate that request to other components via a function call. How do I acheive that if dont have the dll reference?

Comment: Let your first component get the responsibility to make the second call to other components but this components must expose an API too.